# Why does the function $f(z) = 1/\sin(\pi/z)$ have isolated singular points?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity-theory

In the complex analysis text book "Complex Variables and Applications 8th edition", it states the function $1/sin (\pi/z)$ has singular points $z = 0$ and $z = 1/m; (m = \pm 1,2,3,4,\dots.) $

I sort of understand why z=0 is not considered an isolated singular point. However why are all the other singular points isolated? Could you explain this to a math undergrad? Thank-you

Comment: edited, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolated means we can draw a ball around the point and have no other singularities be in that ball.   given a number of the form $z=1/m$, we can draw a sufficiently small ball such that no other number $z=1/n$ is in that ball,  neither is $0$,  so they are isolated.

On the other hand,  there is no ball around $0$ that can avoid numbers of the form $1/m$,  since we can always get as close to 0 as we want with numbers of the form $1/m$, so 0 is not isolated.

Comment: Ahh, I actually don't know why I just realised this now. 1/z gets infinitely smaller and smaller. For some reason I was thinking in the reverse direction; it was getting larger. Thank you!

Comment: no problem, we all do stuff like that sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

For any positive integer $m$, $1/m$ is a finite distance away from its closed neighbours in the set $A =\{ 1/n : n \in \{1,2,3,\dotsc \}\}$. (You can convince yourself of this easily enough: they are obviously $1/(m \pm 1)$, and you can easily subtract these from $1/m$ and take the modulus.)

Hence you can stick an open ball around $1/m$ for any positive integer $m$ so that $1/m$ is the only point of $A$ inside it. This is precisely what isolated means.

Comment: Any integer, actual - the question was vague, but it is $\pm\frac{1}{m}$.